# tex file using emacs editor in Mac

Tags: macos

I am using MacBook air 10.13.1 version. I have installed Texshop for using latex. I have also installed emacs editor, the trouble with me is that previously i was a linux user in which i used to make any new tex file by comanding in terminal " emacs filename.tex&  and then I could easily run and compile  by making dvi file, in this system whenever I do the same the emacs editor opens itself in terminal this is the problem 1, and also I dont know hot to run and compile it in terminal through dvi file process.

Help me if anybody knows how to solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your emacs question has nothing to do with TeX. But I'll say this: The emacs that comes with macOS is a text only emacs. You will want a GUI emacs. Try [this one](https://emacsformacosx.com/), for example. If you have further emacs related questions, there is an emacs community [right here on stackexchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As for how to run (la)tex in the terminal on macOS, it should be no different from what you're used to from linux. Can you restate your question to make it clearer?

Comment: You can install Emacs with Homebrew

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution

> Install emacs for mac

https://emacsformacosx.com/

Go here and grab the .dmg, alternatively you can install aquamacs

http://aquamacs.org/

> Open emacs

To open emacs from the terminal just type

```
$ open -a emacs <file.tex>
```

or

```
$ open -a aquamacs <file.tex>
```

> Compile

Now you can do the things you are used to from linux

```
$ latex <file.tex>
```

Comment: `emacs` is already installed in Mac OS X (albeit not necessarily the latest version and without AucTeX), you only need to type `emacs` in the Terminal to open it.

Comment: @FranckPastor `$ emacs` will not lunch the gui. There are certainly ways around this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171280/how-to-launch-gui-emacs-from-command-line-in-osx